# How do I retrieve the error message thrown by Future from the server to the client?

Tags: meteor

Inside my server, I that checks some data from the database and throws an error when it's not valid. I have it like so:

```
//SERVER CODE:    
    Meteor.methods({

                send: function (prefix, number, content) {
                    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
                    var future = new Future();

                    //do some validation

                    myReference.doSomething({
                        number: number,
                        content: content
                    }, function(error) {
                        if(error) {
                            future.throw("Cannot send at this time.");
                        } else {
                            future.return("SUCCESS");
                        }
                    });

                    return future.wait();
                } 
   });
```

In the **client side**, I would like to get the message "Cannot send at this time." inside `future.throw("Cannot send at this time.");`. Hopefully I could show it inside an alert. How do I do that?

Currently, this is what I'm trying and I keep getting some undefined error.

```
//CLIENT CODE    
Meteor.call("send", prefix, number, content, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    alert(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("SUCCESSFULLY SENT. ", result);
                    }

                });
```

This is the error I get when trying to get the error message:

```
    errorClass: Internal server error [500] 
{
error: 500, 
reason: "Internal server error", 
details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", 
errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}
details: undefined
error: 500
errorType: "Meteor.Error"
message: "Internal server error [500]"reason: 
"Internal server error"stack: (...)get 
stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: 
function () { [native code] }__proto__: Middle
```

How do I get the error message that I threw from future?

Comment: Could you try with _future.throw(error);_ ?

Comment: Can't you just `throw new Error('Cannot send at this time')` ? What is `future.throw` giving you?

Comment: `future` supposed to give possibility to call async methods (i.e. external API calls) inside Meteor server-side methods. Currently I have the same problem with `throw`, though, I do `.throw` not in the async method in my case but before returning `future.wait()`. I have several `.throw` in async callback too but this particular is about argument validation. I suppose changing it to throw new Error() will help, though it isn't intuitive approach _at all_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like that: `return future.throw(new Meteor.Error(400, 'ololo'))`

future.throw expects an Meteor.Error instance that in it's turn contains error message itself and additionally http response code. So `400` is `Bad Request` response code in that case and `ololo` is error message.

`return` isn't actually necessary here but I do it every time just to be sure I don't call any code after failure.